# Receiving error message when initialising JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So below is my javascript code. It's wrapped in module.exports, but that's not the error.

```
 parseMention = (arg, asId = false) => {
    if(!arg.startsWith('<@') && arg.endsWith('>')) return undefined
    let id = arg.slice(2, -1)
    if(id.startsWith('!')) id.slice(1)
    if(asId === true) return id
    if(asId === false) return bot.users.cache.get(id)
}
```

despite it seeming correct to me, I get the following error message:

> SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please add the code portion where you're invoking this method...

Comment: What are you doing here, //if(id.startsWith('!')) id.slice(1)// id.slice(1) returns an another array you are not assigning that returned array to any where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's wrapped in module.exports, but that's not the error.

I'm pretty sure there is the error.

This part of your code won't throw a `SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer` error. It would be great to see your `module.exports`, but it's 99.9% that you're trying to export an object like this and the `=` after `parseMention` is an invalid shorthand property initialiser:

```js
// This is invalid syntax
module.exports = {
  parseMention = (arg, asId = false) => {
    if (!arg.startsWith('<@') && arg.endsWith('>')) return undefined;
    let id = arg.slice(2, -1);
    if (id.startsWith('!')) id.slice(1);
    if (asId === true) return id;
    if (asId === false) return bot.users.cache.get(id);
  }
}
```

This should work:

```js
module.exports = {
  parseMention(arg, asId = false) {
    if (!arg.startsWith('<@') && arg.endsWith('>')) return undefined;
    let id = arg.slice(2, -1);
    // it won't do anything, slice won't mutate id and you don't return
    if (id.startsWith('!')) id.slice(1);
    if (asId === true) return id;
    if (asId === false) return bot.users.cache.get(id);
  },
};
```